# No funciona el estilo en mi proyecto

Tags: python, css, django

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Django y quiero agregar CSS a mi proyecto pero no carga.
**Mi template:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/style.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Listado de los nombres</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for i in nombreslista  %}
     {% if i == "Martin"  %}
        <li class="progamador">{{i}}</li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="analista">{{i}}</li>
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

En **Settings.py** tengo esto. Probe con *"/static/"* y tampoco funciona

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```